# Android gradle flavor Alternate java Code files

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

In my app I have 3 productFlavors,
2 of which should use the same class file and the third one should use other class file (same class name different content)

I'm trying to avoid duplicating the class file into 2 flavor directories.

this is my configuration:
Im trying to make x86 and armv7 to use the same java resource
and the "other" to use a different one

```
productFlavors {
        armv7 {
            versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode + 2
            minSdkVersion 14
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", ""
            }

        }
        x86 {
            versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode + 4
            minSdkVersion 14
           ndk {
                abiFilters "x86", ""
              }
        }
        other {
            versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode + 0
            minSdkVersion 10

        }

 }
```

thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that in next way. Move your common class into standalone directory `not_other`, for example, and include it into both flavors at`sourceSets`, see `build.gradle` bellow

```
android{
      ...
        productFlavors{
        armv7 {
           ...
        }
        x86  {
           ...
        }
        other  {
           ....
        }
    }

    sourceSets{
        armv7.java.srcDirs = ['src/armv7/java', 'src/not_other/java']
        x86.java.srcDirs = ['src/x86/java', 'src/not_other/java']
    }
}
```